# Help create a unit test for test response header, specifically Cache-Control, in determining if caching has been disable or not

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, model-view-controller, caching, cache-control

Scenario:

I have a base controller which disables caching within the OnActionExecuting override.

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); //IE
    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore(); //FireFox 
}
```

How can I create a Unit Test to test this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to do the same. The best I have so far is this...

```
    [TestCase]
    public void ResponseNotFromCache()
    {

            System.Net.WebRequest rq = System.Net.WebRequest.Create("testmethod");
            System.Net.HttpWebResponse rs = rq.GetResponse() as System.Net.HttpWebResponse;

            Assert.IsFalse(rs.IsFromCache);
    }
```

There must be a better way!

Update: [How can I test an event of a MVC controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678927/how-can-i-test-an-event-of-a-mvc-controller)